# Maintain state of application when Internet connection loses in android

Tags: android, connection, android-networking

In my app, internet is being used. What I have to do is, I have to check internet connection when my application runs. When I first start the app, it checks, whether internet connection is available or not in device. Internet connection can be through Wi-Fi or Mobile. If, any of these is available then and only then my app should work, else it should prompt message. I have done this till. Below is my code...

```
public final boolean isInternetOn() {

          ConnectivityManager connec =  
                       (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                 connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                 connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                 connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) 
Toast.makeText(this, " Connected ", 1000).show();{
                 return true;

            } else if ( 
              connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||
              connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {

                Toast.makeText(this, " Not Connected ", 1000).show();
                return false;
            }
          return false;
        }
```

I have done till this. But what I want is, when user moves to second activity, and if internet connection loses, then state of app should be maintained. And when internet connection is activated again, then app should work properly from Second activity onward. What needs to be done?